# RegEx match if present

Tags: regex

Is there something in regex to match (conditionally) only if it exists ?

e.g.

the string maybe

```
question_1
```

or only

```
question
```

In case of the former, it should match the  integer in the end, but as in the case of the latter, it should leave it.

Comment: What does "leave it" mean? Do you want to match either string regardless of whether or not there is an underscore and a number at the end?

Comment: This question denotes a null knowledge of Regexes. Not even zero. Null. SO isn't a tutorial. When you post here you should know at least the basics of the argument you are asking about.

Comment: Are you trying to say, If there is an underscore, a number must be followed, otherwise there should be no underscore at the end ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `?` is the 0-1 quantifier in Regexes. `\d?` means 0 or 1 digit. The `*` is the 0-infinite quantifier. `\d*` means 0 or more digits. Is it what you want?
(additionally the `+` is the 1 or more quantifier, and not quantifier means exactly 1)

To elaborate on what you asked, I would say

```
question(_\d+)?
```

`question` followed by an optional (`_` AND 1 or more digits)

Where the brackets are only to group the sub expression (they are "mathematical" brackets)

Answer (score 3):

Don't quite understand the question. Do you just want to extract the number?

```
question_(\d+)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the number
`question(?:_?)(\d)?`

Answer (score 1):

in perl you could do something like:

```
my $string = 'question_1';
my $question_number = $string =~ /question_(\d+)/i;
```

now `$question_number` will hold the int if it matches and will be `undef` if it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

If the underscore and the number are optional try something like this:

> `question(?:_\d)?`

Comment: He tried to say, if there is an underscore, then a number should be present. otherwise, only the "question" without no ending _